# How do I change the background color of the Query Result window in Oracle SQL Developer?

Tags: themes, oracle-sqldeveloper

Overall I would like to have a dark theme for Oracle SQL Developer.

I know that I can go to the menu item Window/Preferences, Code Editor/PL/SQL Syntax Colors and select the "Twilight" Scheme and the SQL Worksheet window will look as expected.

[image: Window/Preferences Pop Up]

However, all other non SQL Worksheet windows in the applications remain super bright white which is a strain on the eyes.  (I have intentionally obscured the data in the image below.)

[image: After applying scheme]

Is there a way to make the background dark on the other windows such as the Query Result window?

Answer (score 13):

You can do this -

[image]

Preferences - Database - Worksheet: Grid in checker board or Zebra pattern

This pattern isn't configurable, but it is much nicer than the stark White background.

Comment: that is definitely an improvement!

Comment: That option could easily be enabled by default. It would be great to have more "standard" colors like light gray or light blue. What makes it a bit confusing is the fact the zebra  applies to the columns too. Lines need this because they are thin. Not the case of most columns.